# How can I make a tablet use same menu as phone with twitter bootstrap v 3.1.1?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navigation, tablet

I am trying to get it so that when I load my website on a tablet, specifically an iPad, in portrait mode, it uses the collapsed menu just like when I load it on my iPhone. I tried the customization feature on http://getbootstrap.com but it didn't work. I also tried a few different posts I saw on StackOverflow, but they didn't work for me either.

Comment: Could you post what you have at the moment? It shouldn't be hard if you're using the built-in classes: i.e. `col-xs-2` becomes `col-md-2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't bootstrap. It was me! I after trying to format the code to paste nicely into stackoverflow, I notice I had an extra `</div>`. After removing this, it works perfect!

Comment: It says I still have to wait 17 hours to accept it. As soon as it allows me to I will.